Coprime polynomials in a non-principal prime ideal of $k[x,y]$
The problem is stated below:

Let $I\subset k[x,y]$ be a prime ideal. If $I$ is not principal, then
(1) there exist at least two coprime polynomials $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ in $I$;
(2) $V(f,g)\subset \mathbf A^2$ has finite points at most.

I searched for a classification of the prime ideals of $k[x,y]$ and I've learned that the ideal $I$ satisfying the conditions is the maximal ideal $(x-a,y-b)$ of $k[x,y]$. But I don't know how to solve (2).
thanks:)

Using $(1)$, could you come up with necessary conditions for any points $(x,y) \in V(f,g)$?

(1) Your claim holds only for algebraically closed fields. In general let $p\in I$ be an irreducible polynomial. If all polynomials in $I$ are not coprime with $p$, then $I\subsetneq(p)$, so the height of $(p)$ is at least two, a contradiction.
